# What is a Regex equivalent of the 'Trim' function used in languages such as VB and Java..?

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

I'm using Regex in a Microsoft Access 2007 database with a VBA project reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5.

All is well...mostly. I would like to know a Regular Expression that will act like the 'Trim' function..? (remove leading and trailing spaces)

I have this: ((?:.?)*) which is to "capture everything after the last match". But it always matches extra spaces which I would like to remove.

Below is the relevant code, followed by a screenshot of the debugger. Item 4 in the submatches has " CAN". How do I remove the space with Regex, so I don't have to use the Trim function..?

```
pattern = "^(\d{1,2})(?:\/)(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,3})?)(OZ)((?:.?)*)"
regex.pattern = pattern
Set matchCollection = regex.Execute(workstring)
If matchCollection.Count > 0 Then
    matchSection = "LOOSE CASES"
    itemtype = "CASE"
    percase = matchCollection(0).SubMatches(0)
    perpack = 1
    unitsize = matchCollection(0).SubMatches(1)
    uom = matchCollection(0).SubMatches(2)
    other = VBA.Trim(matchCollection(0).SubMatches(3))
End If
```

...
[image: debugger]

Comment: I think it is `^\s+|\s+$`.

Comment: @mike And what is the point to match an empty string? `\s*` makes no sense neither for matching (what are empty strings for?) nor for replacing (what's the point of replacing an empty string with an empty string?).

Comment: It's for matching excess passages of whitespace. For instance, any of the trailing spaces and/or carriage returns at the end of the string. A more logical choice might be \s+, so one-or-more of whitespace, instead of none-or-more, because as you say, what's the point of matching nothing. However, I would suppose in some cases of complex expressions, the choice to use * over + might make it more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out. To reiterate (and clarify): my original regex ((?:.?)*) is meant to "capture anything left after the last match". But it also captured leading & trailing spaces.

Removing the leading spaces was fairly easy, but every attempt to remove the trailing spaces was foiled by the * in the group. Then I read about \b and dropped one in and now it works.

This is what I have now: (?: ?)((?:.?)*)\b(?: *) which is "match anything left after the last match, except leading or trailing spaces".

And in context, this is the whole of it...

(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})PK-(\d{1,2}(?:.\d{1,3})?)(OZ|ML)(?: ?)((?:.?)*)\b(?: *)

Which is meant to match on a string such as this...

2/12PK-11.125OZ CAN RET

...which describes cases of beer in our warehouse. =-)